# Pandas save duplicate excel sheets with ExcelWriter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to save multiple dataframe as a separate sheet in an excel notebook. For this, my code looks like this

```
output_file = "normalized_desertrose.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

sheet_names = ['Stem', 'Caudex', 'Buds8', 'Buds10', 'Buds12', 'Budsgrowth8', 
           'Budsgrowth10', 'Budsgrowth12', 'Leaves8', 'Leaves10', 'Leaves12', 
           'Leafarea', 'Flowerbud day1', 'Flowerbud day2', 'Bloom', 'Total Flower']

for sheet in sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel('desertrose_ed.xlsx',shee_name=sheet)
    print("Sheet is {}".format(sheet))
    print("--------------------------")
    
    x = df.values
    cols = df.columns
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled,columns=cols)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet)
    for col in cols:
        print("Column is {}".format(col))
        mean = df[col].mean()
        std = np.std(df[col])
        if mean == 0:
            variation = 0.0
        else:
            variation = (std*1.0)/mean
        standard_error = std/math.sqrt(len(df))
        print("Mean {}\nStandard deviation {}\nCofficient of variation {}\nStandard error {}\n".format(mean,std,variation,standard_error))    

writer.save()
```

I see different sheets in my output excel notebook, but they all have same data.

Can anyone let me know where I am committing the mistake ? I think I am missing something, just not sure where.

Comment: The code is missing variables, like `sheet_names`. Please ensure a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also the `sheet_name` variable is spelt incorrectly in `pd.read_excel`

Comment: @WBM Hi, sorry somehow I missed it while copying. Please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading the excel file multiple times, I suggest you read it once and access the values in the dictionary:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('desertrose_ed.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
for sheet in dfs.keys():
    print("Sheet is {}".format(sheet))
    print("--------------------------")
  
    x = dfs[sheet].values
    cols = dfs[sheet].columns
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
    df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled,columns=cols)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet)
    for col in cols:
        print("Column is {}".format(col))
        mean = df[col].mean()
        std = np.std(df[col])
        if mean == 0:
            variation = 0.0
        else:
            variation = (std*1.0)/mean
        standard_error = std/math.sqrt(len(df))
        print("Mean {}\nStandard deviation {}\nCofficient of variation {}\nStandard error {}\n".format(mean,std,variation,standard_error))    

writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank @Celius, I will try it out and will update. The writer and output file name needs not to be changed, right ? Also, in your modified code, I could see you are just importing the sheets in a different way, your writing to output is similar to mine.. Is it that my import was making some problems ?

Comment: Yes, I believe output file name and writer  are correct so they don't need to be changed. I couldn't really find an obvious cause for your problem, but it must have something to do with how `df` is working (considering there's no more code which you are not providing). Hopefully this solution will help you solve the issue.

Comment: I dont know what exactly made a difference but your code worked like charm. Thanks a ton.